# What is the justification for the New international Version and New Living Translation's translation of Philippians 2:6?

Tags: jesus, philippians, niv, nlt

Philippians 2:6 NIV Who, **being in very nature** God, did not consider equality with God something to be used to his own advantage

Philippians 2:6 NLT **Though he was God**, he did not think of equality with God as something to cling to

Philippians 2:6 ASV who, **existing in the form of God**, counted not the being on an equality with God a thing to be grasped

Philippians 2:6 YLT who, **being in the form of God**, thought it not robbery to be equal to God,

Most translations from Bible Hub show "in the form of God" but not NIV and NLT. What is the justification for NIV's and NLT's translation of Philippians 2:6?

Comment: You should study a bit about the translation nuances and purposes. Not all translations are literal word for word. NIV and NLT particularly are aimed for a simplistic translation for easy understandability. Many times such translation would convey the meaning better than the hard translations to the readers.  Studying about translation methods would save you from asking many questions in the same line.

Comment: Michael this may be the best place available for some people to ask the question, making the Hermeneutics site valuable. And translation philosophy certainly falls within the purview of Hermeneutics. We surely do well to learn more in depth, but asking questions for beginners is also helpful. That said, by all means, study more.

Comment: Rather than repeat what I perceive, you can see my comment under @Jesse Steele below. Upvoted + 1.

Comment: @Olde English. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael16. Thank you for your comment. Can you please expound and answer my question.

Comment: I dont think I can add any more than the explanation that being in the form of God is same as being in the nature of God, having nature of God, being God in the simplistic and dynamic equivalence translations. Remember that NLT and NIV are not hard word for word translations.

Answer (score 4):

## I interviewed Dr. Taylor (NLT) on Bible translation

Your Question is about how Bible translators think. This is a good and normal curiosity for many Bible readers, which we should allow on the Hermeneutics site.

I was in a Bible introduction class at Moody, and our group was assigned to research the Living Bible. The New Living Translation was Ken Taylor's second translation, which he oversaw through multiple committees. He personally translated the Living, but gave me a copy of the NLT when I met with him.

I later went back and told him about the NLT, "I like your translation, but for word studies I prefer the NASB."

Dr. Taylor replied, *"I agree with your analysis. If we are going to study the words, we need to have the words. But, this [NLT] is for the people to be able to understand."*

That was his defense on how he translated the NLT the way he did.

### I have done Bible translation from Greek

I think you are trying to ask why it *may* have been translated the way it was—essentially asking about the rationale behind Bible translation. You're not asking the translators directly, you're asking people with experience to explain the thinking of Bible translators in general.

Remember, different Bible translations have different purposes. Translators keep those purposes in mind to make their translations different from other translations, thus more useful to Bible readers.

The Greek text in question:

Philipians 2:6 ([greekbible.com](https://greekbible.com))

> ὃς ἐν μορφῇ θεοῦ ὑπάρχων οὐχ ἁρπαγμὸν ἡγήσατο τὸ εἶναι ἴσα θεῷ,

The text you are boldfacing is literally "in form of God being" from "ἐν μορφῇ θεοῦ ὑπάρχων" (eno morphae theou huparchoen). You can see in there the word for "morph" or "form".

### Why, then? Speculating based on experience

I have translated the Book of Revelation. I've also taught mature adults and young children, reading from Greek and translating as I read for understanding at their level. I wrestle with these questions constantly myself.

The NIV and NLT translators ***probably*** felt that "form" might diminish the Soteriological claims of who Jesus was. They ***probably*** wouldn't want readers to get any impression of "merely form of, but not really, God". I certainly know Dr. Taylor would have felt that way as his rationale behind the NLT.

### NIV & NLT differences

I lived in the Grand Rapids, Michigan area almost 30 years and rubbed shoulders with Zondervan editors, which publishes NIV. Zondervan (NIV) aims more at "adult basic understanding" while Tyndale (NLT) gives a little more focus toward children.

The NIV tends to have a word in English for a word in Greek, translating "form"/morph as "nature". But, the NIV is hardly a "word-for-word" translation as the NASB is. The NLT tried to be just a little more unbound by word-for-word translation than NIV, aiming just a little more for the understanding of the reader.

Wanting children to understand, the NLT translators likely think that differentiating between "God being in the form of God" vs "God being God" splits hairs without understanding and only causes confusion.

When I talk to seven year olds, I certainly don't try to explain how "form" is different from "substance"; Tyndale House probably doesn't want to either.

Hence, NIV would naturally want to use "nature" for adult easy reading while NLT would naturally just leave it out to avoid confusion.

---

### Theological influence

*Afterthought:*

It came up in the discussion that the omission in NLT and alternate of NIV term "nature" are based on presumptions of the Trinitarian publishers. Both Tyndale (NLT) and Zondervan (NIV) are Trinitarian, at least in reputation (churches 'have' doctrine, publishers 'favor' doctrine). Both their theology—and the theology of their readers especially—directed their choices as a matter of course. They wouldn't and shouldn't say so in the translation notes within their circles because of their own shared presumptions. Trinitarians will expectedly translate Trinitarian. We can't fault them for that, but we should surely observe.

Similar presumptions in translation occur with the worldviews of Mandarin and English speakers I have encountered in Taiwan over the last 12 years. So back to the OP: Why? Theological presumptions are indeed a more than 0% factor. I don't want to dive too deep in that because that should be discussed on Christianity.SE. This approaches the overlap of Hermeneutics and Christianity/SysTheo.

On a personal note, I would try to use some word understandable to both children and adult readers, not just omit. The "likeness", "form", and "nature" aspect of the incarnation of Christ is a fascinating concept behind the text. This concept existed in the minds of the NT writers. I don't understand the concept perfectly myself, so I can't make assumptions on the best way to translate text that affects our understanding on that concept.

We want translation of their words to express that beauty in their ideas. None of us know how to do that perfectly. That's why Tyndale was founded by Dr. Taylor, to offer yet one more perspective/translation to assist discussion as we collectively read a text to understand more of what can never be fully understood.

In other words, I would try to limit my own theology's influence on translation and try to let the text come through so as to be the influence on my ongoing development of theology. I couldn't do it perfectly, though. No other translator can either.

Comment: You make a good point regarding why translators choose a certain path. Unfortunately, most seem oblivious to this reasoning and the NIV (for eg.) is widely used as a *truth* bible, when it is not, sometimes, even close.

Comment: The answer to why the translators of the NLT and NIV translated the way they did may actually be more to do with **bias** than simplicity in the understanding thereof, and the **Trinitarian** *bias* is *unmistakable* here.

Comment: @OldeEnglish that is an inescapable reality, yes. “Simple” and “understandable” according to their SysTheo. I would translate it to avoid that, even for children.

Comment: Glad to hear that from you but that didn't come across in your answer. You seemed to be at peace with the *exegesis* of the NLT and NIV translators to my mind. I suggest that an edit *may* be in order.

Comment: That's an informative answer, Jesse. The NLT is not just for children, though. It is also for adults who prefer an easy-to-understand version. They made a mistake on this verse, however, because "form of God" is easy to understand and to leave out μορφῇ distorts the meaning of the text. Nice to see you would avoid that.

Comment: @OldeEnglish The problem with an edit like this would be scope creep. It’s about hermeneutics and that would venture into Christianity.SE. I have seen a mod state somewhere previously in SE that comments are the perfect place for this. I’d be open to a meta about it, though, and a new Question on the influence theology has in translation. I greatly respect Dr Taylor’s work, but I often scratch my head at NIV. I tried to use an objective tone, tho. Seems I succeeded there.

Comment: @MartinHemsley Largely agree with your comment, except I wouldn’t say that anyone “made a mistake” on a judgement call in regards to something so discretionary as translation of any content. I would regard a “translation mistake” as translating something like “barking” into “fish bowl”; anything much less than that diff and I would only go so far to say I didn’t agree. My view also comes from living in Taiwan and dealing with Mandarin-English differences on the street.

Comment: I sense that you are obfuscating. You seemingly have no *real* objection to the **Trinitarian** approach, which is probably why you don't *really* feel an edit is warranted. I would have liked to have seen you go beyond the *objective tone* myself, but then again, I'm an unapologetic *non-Trinitarian*, but nevertheless a seeker of truly *responsible* translation of the ancient languages. I feel no further need for discourse here, as I see it devolving into possible argument.

Comment: @OldeEnglish Rather than meta, I'll take this discussion to suffice. And, you are fair in all you say. I am 95% Trinitarian (5% unfinished) but I didn't initially address that because both publishers in question are also. I will update my answer to note that because our theology really does affect translation, even without knowing. Thank you for this, also on healthy discussion practices!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jesse. I realize you have reasons for the stance you take but when we translate scripture, we are held to a much higher standard. You must know that from having translated Revelation. "God" and "form of God" express two very different concepts. Regardless of our theological or experiential biases, I don't think we have any defensible justification for imposing  a change like that in scripture. Btw, I love the "5% unfinished" remark. I appreciate your humility.

Comment: @MartinHemsley Higher standards—I try in all things. I admit that, while I would not omit the word, I'm inwardly glad Dr. Taylor did so we can have important discussions like this. I think he would want that also because he knew his own translation couldn't be perfect; that's why he translated the Bible twice. GK Chesterton: Books are never finished, only abandoned.

Comment: The answer has been updated to reflect the comments above. I'd like to consider that discussion closed for now, a meta discussion would be welcome if we need more.

Comment: You are an *enigma*, a bit of a mystery for sure. If it wasn't for your first comment to Martin, which was a little too *flippant* for my liking, I might have been inclined to vote you up, particularly after your edit. Liked your acknowledgement to the importance of text. Did not like the fact that you are a proponent of the incarnation of Christ. I, myself, am a proponent of the incarnation and manifestation of the **Word**, who didn't become the **Christ/Messiah** until at least his earthly baptism, although I have questioned even that on this site, but that's another story.

Comment: @OldeEnglish I didn't intend to be flippant at all. Could be a misunderstanding. Trying to be brief, respectful, and on-point. Theology banter is always fun, but yes, we must curb our love for chasing foxes in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I am probably expressing a minority view here but I believe it is the correct one and people can feel free to push back if they wish. It seems there have been several variations on this question lately which shows me that it must be important. It is also interesting to me that I have not come across a single accurate translation of this text, and again, I am open to someone proving me wrong. I suspect most people will merely be able to say, “You have your opinion and I have mine.”
Here’s the Greek, so the language scholars can verify easily.

> 6Ὃς ἐν μορφῇ Θεοῦ ὑπάρχων οὐχ ἁρπαγμὸν ἡγήσατο τὸ εἶναι ἴσα Θεῷ

A rough literal translations would be

> Who in form of God existing, not considered robbery to be equal to
> God.

So, how could this be translated faithfully in readable English? There are different options that don’t affect the meaning, but I would suggest something like this.

> Who, though existing in the form of God, did not consider seizing
> equality with God.

So the text clearly shows that for Jesus to become equal to God, he would have had to try to seize something that was not meant for him to attain. I realize that centuries of church history and doctrine would have us think otherwise but I believe this translation fits much better with what the rest of the Bible says about the relationship between the Father and the Son, such as Jesus saying that the Father is greater than he and his current place now at the right hand of the Father, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Let us now revisit the two translations mentioned in the question above.

> Philippians 2:6 NIV Who, being in very nature God, did not consider
> equality with God something to be used to his own advantage

> Philippians 2:6 NLT Though he was God, he did not think of equality
> with God as something to cling to

To me, it’s a pretty big leap to go from form (appearance) to nature (essence). The NLT leaves out "form" altogether.  Why do they do this? I believe they have a theological bias to show that Jesus was equal to the Father. Ironically, the Greek is saying exactly the opposite.

Comment: I hope people will judge this and all answers, for that matter, based on the hermeneutics and not whether it agrees with what they have been taught all their lives. We must not be afraid to examine our beliefs in the light of scripture. Personally, I have never down-voted anybody for clearly presenting a reason for their beliefs, and I have nothing against my brothers and sisters who sincerely hold differing opinions.

Comment: Nice job Martin. You have my vote.

Comment: Martin,
Great job  explaining this as well as in the spirit you wrote it.
Unlearning things is much harder sometimes then learning new things.  Traditional teaching doesn't make things true.  Teachers that we love can also  prevent us from hearing the truth if we truly are questioning things that we once held tightly to be true.

Comment: Thanks, Sherrie. Yes, we don't want to hold on so tightly to doctrines that we can't objectively examine them in the light of the Word. One of the most important things I try to teach people is not to rely too much on any teacher, including me. We will all be held individually accountable for what we have believed and how we have put it into useful action for the kingdom. God bless your faithful heart!

Comment: 'seizing' or 'robbery' is best rendered 'violative appropriation'.  The text is saying that Jesus did not consider equality with God as something that was misappropriated.  In other words, He didn't humble Himself because equality with God was wrong.  Paul's point is that He humbled Himself even though there was nothing wrong with the equality He had:  that Christ, in the form of God, did not consider equality with God to be a violation of property rights, social codes or personal autonomy.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**
In addition to those answers which examine the different translation philosophy, I would add there is a legitimate hermeneutical approach which justifies nature.

> Who, while being in *the* form *of* God, did not regard the being equal *with* God *a* thing-to-be-grasped (DLNT)
> ὃς ἐν μορφῇ θεοῦ ὑπάρχων οὐχ ἁρπαγμὸν ἡγήσατο τὸ εἶναι ἴσα θεῷ

The Disciples Literal New Testament uses *form* which is probably the better word-for-word treatment of [μορφῇ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3444/kjv/tr/0-1/). Note however, the DLNT italicizes *the* and *of* to show the translator understood them as ellipses. The literal Greek is *morphē theou*: there is no article. The literal Greek differs from an English interpretation of **the** form/appearance/nature of **the** God.

If *morphē* is taken as form or appearance, that hardly settles the meaning, because how does the form or appearance **of God** exist apart from the nature of God? In other words, it is true *morphē* most likely envisions that which is external, but how can one have *morphē theou*, which is external of God, independent of that which is internal, or by nature God? Arguably, the only way one has the external form or appearance of God is by also possessing what is by nature God. Conceptually, neither form, appearance, or nature do justice to the phrase Paul has constructed. Any attempt to use the lexicon to understand the intended meaning as either form, or appearance, or nature will fall short of conveying Paul's meaning.

**Glory**
What form or appearance would agree with Paul's terminology? Contextually, the outward appearance would be glory which is how the passage begins and ends:

> Let nothing be done through strife or **vainglory**; but in lowliness of mind let each esteem other better than themselves. (2:3 KJV)
> μηδὲν κατ᾽ ἐριθείαν μηδὲ κατὰ **κενοδοξίαν** ἀλλὰ τῇ ταπεινοφροσύνῃ ἀλλήλους ἡγούμενοι ὑπερέχοντας ἑαυτῶν

> and every tongue should confess-out that Jesus Christ *is* Lord, to *the* **glory** *of* God *the* Father. (2:11 DLNT)
> καὶ πᾶσα γλῶσσα ἐξομολογήσηται ὅτι κύριος Ἰησοῦς Χριστὸς εἰς **δόξαν** θεοῦ πατρός

Paul begins by encouraging the Philippians to do nothing out of self-seeking glory and ends with the phrase δόξαν θεοῦ πατρός, glory *theou* Father. Understanding *morphē theou* as glory agrees with what Jesus said of Himself:

> <sup>4</sup> I glorified you on earth, having accomplished the work that you gave me to do. <sup>5</sup> And now, Father, glorify me in your own presence with the glory that I had with you before the world existed. (John 17 ESV)

Philippians 2 fits what is found in the Fourth Gospel. Jesus had *morphē theou*, glory with the Father before the world was. He emptied Himself of this glory in order to take on the form of a slave. In this case, Paul is making a parenthetical statement to the Gospel tradition. He has added the details of how the prayer was answered.

> <sup>9</sup> Therefore God also highly-exalted Him, and granted Him the name above every name <sup>10</sup> in-order-that every knee should bow at the name *of* Jesus— *of* heavenly *ones* and earthly *ones* and *ones* under-the-earth— <sup>11</sup> and every tongue should confess-out that Jesus Christ *is* Lord, to *the* glory *of* God *the* Father. (DLNT)

In addition to receiving back that of which He emptied Himself, He was more highly exalted.

**Holiness**
What "nature" of God does Jesus have? He was without sin (cf. [Hebrews 4:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%204%3A15&version=ESV)). Being without sin, He would be holy. The sense of being holy is to be separate. Since sin separates man from God who is holy, Jesus emptied Himself of that which by nature separates man from God. This was accomplished by taking on human form, which is the from of a slave (cf. [Romans 6:16-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%206%3A16-19&version=ESV)). That is, He who was without sin and was holy had the appearance of a sinner who by nature had the appearance of being separated from God.

**Conclusion**
Based upon the New Testament, form, appearance, and nature all fit Paul's use and can reasonably used to translate the phrase. If there is any inaccuracy in translating *morphē theou* as "nature of God" it lies in capturing only part of the full meaning. Yet the same could be said of "form/appearance of God." If one was to use a single word, in my opinion it would be "glory."

Answer (score 0):

Young's Literal Translation Philippians 2:

> 6a
> who, being in the form of God,

being
ὑπάρχων (hyparchōn)
Verb - Present Participle Active - Nominative Masculine Singular
Strong's 5225: To begin, am, exist, be in possession. From hupo and archomai; to begin under, i.e. Come into existence; expletively, to exist (verb).

[the] form
μορφῇ (morphē)
Noun - Dative Feminine Singular
Strong's 3444: Form, shape, outward appearance. Perhaps from the base of meros; shape; figuratively, nature.

YLT uses a more literal methodology in its translation.
American Standard Version has done similarly:

> who, existing in the form of God

These are more conservative translations for English-speaking natives.
On the other hand, NIV adopted a more dynamic strategy, translating the concept indicated by the word:

> Who, being in very nature God

NIV appeals to the international English readers/scholars whose mother tongue may not be English.

New Living Translation took this translation liberty another step:

> Though he was God

Read Jesse Steele's answer for further explanation of NLT translation philosophy.

What is the justification for the New international Version and New Living Translation's translation of Philippians 2:6?

Basically, NIV and NLT are more liberal compared with YLT and ASV. There are advantages and disadvantages to every translation. I advocate reading more than just one version.
Particularly, when it comes to proving a doctrine, like in this case, do not just rely on just one single translation.
Relying on a single liberal translation could really mess things up.

Comment: The NIV and the NLT may be more liberal in their translations but if they succeed in altering the *true* meaning, which I believe they have, to support their more than obvious *Trinitarian* biases, rather than *true* exegesis, then how can they be *advocating* for *accurate knowledge*, which we should all be able to seek, without naked deceit, when all is said and done.

Comment: That's why I advocate reading more than just one version :)

Comment: All you have done, here, is point out differences. You weren't advocating any such thing. You finish up by saying...*there are advantages and disadvantages to every translation.* You would have done better to have said...*Reader beware. Don't put one's faith in just one rendition of the ancient languages. check out others*, and remember, **context is key**.

Comment: I added. Thanks :)

Comment: You're getting closer.

Comment: Added some more :)

Comment: Added some more again. Thanks for the reader beware warning :)

Comment: You stopped short of saying **context is key**, so I'm going to pass on this one. Appreciate the fact that you didn't dismiss me out of hand though.